# use char as an operator?

Tags: android, arduino

I am making an android app + arduino that will receive ir code from arduino and sending the `results.value` (ir decode) to android through bluetooth. on the android side I have receive the code as a String that results into (for example) 92c0 then made a test button that will send it back to arduino and trigger it to send ir code to a device by `irsend.sendNEC(0x92c0, 32)` problem is when receiving the codes back from the android app is I have to receive it by `char data`, how do I use `data` which is a char and use it as a substitute for 0x92c0 in `irsend.sendN` My sketch down below:

```
 #include <IRremote.h>
 #include <SoftwareSerial.h>



 SoftwareSerial bluetoothPort(4,5);
 const int RECV_PIN = 12;
 char data = "0";
 const int SEND_PIN = 13;

 IRsend irsend;


 IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);

 decode_results results;
 int BTval;
 int IRval;



 void setup() 
 {
   bluetoothPort.begin(9600);
   Serial.begin(9600);
   irrecv.enableIRIn();

 }




 void loop() 
 {
   if(bluetoothPort.available() > 0)
   {
     data = bluetoothPort.read();
     Serial.print(data);
     irsend.sendNEC(operator[data],32);
     irrecv.resume();
   }
   if(irrecv.decode(&results))
   {
     Serial.println(results.value);
     int set = results.value;
     bluetoothPort.println(results.value, HEX);
     irrecv.resume();


   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you CAN'T transfer 0x92c0 as a char (or byte). Just because it is not a byte, but two.

Now, I'm not much into android, so I need to see the android code to make a real solution You can handle this in three ways:

1. Binary transfer the data (2 bytes)
2. Transfer the data as a string (5 bytes)
3. Index the possible replies in an array and transfer the index (only applicable for a small quantity of codes).

I'm showing you the last 2, because the 1st is the most effective but I don't think you have the proper knowledge to send and receive data in binary format from android (and surely I don't have it).

So, if the data is transferred in string format (the same way you are uploading it) you will receive more bytes:

- 1 to 4 hexadecimal digits
- 1 carriage return

The code just stores the bytes you receive in a variable and then sends it when you receive a CR or LF:

```
// Outside the loop function
uint16_t receivedData;

// Inside the loop function
if(bluetoothPort.available() > 0)
{
    data = bluetoothPort.read();

    if ((data >= '0') && (data <= '9'))
    { // If it is a digit between 0 and 9 (in ascii)
        receivedData = (receivedData << 4) | (data - '0');
    }
    else if ((data >= 'A') && (data <= 'F'))
    { // If it is a digit between A and F (in ascii)
        receivedData = (receivedData << 4) | (data - 'A' + 10);
    }
    else if ((data >= 'a') && (data <= 'f'))
    { // Lowercase case
        receivedData = (receivedData << 4) | (data - 'a' + 10);
    }
    else if (((data == '\r') || (data == '\n')) && (receivedData > 0))
    { // I tend to consider both CR and LF, because windows always screws this
        Serial.print(receivedData, HEX);
        irsend.sendNEC(receivedData,32); // Not sure about the 32 here...
        irrecv.resume();
        receivedData = 0;
    }
    else
        receivedData = 0; // Something went wrong, just reset the variable
}
```

If you just have to send a few codes, you can store them and then transfer only the proper index. For instance:

```
// Outside the loop function
uint16_t possibleCodes[] = { 0x92c0, 0x8238, 0x5555 };

// Inside the loop function
if(bluetoothPort.available() > 0)
{
    data = bluetoothPort.read();
    // If you are using string transmission, use the following
    // line to get the correct value
    // data = bluetoothPort.read() - '0';

    if (data < sizeof(possibleCodes) / sizeof(possibleCodes[0]))
    {
        Serial.print(possibleCodes[data], HEX);
        irsend.sendNEC(possibleCodes[data],32); // Not sure about the 32 here...
        irrecv.resume();
    }
}
```

For instance in this case to send 0x92c0 you will have to send from android the value 0.